# Adding Web reference to CLR console application gives error C1083

Tags: c++, asp.net, web-services, web-applications, clr

As soon as I add Web reference to CLR console application (as mentioned in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14hykb68%28VS.80%29.aspx), It gives the file missing error message like this

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Hello.h': No such file or directory c1xx

In the application Hello.h file should have been automatically added. In the Solution explorer Generated files folder, the Hello.h file indicates with red (-) sign means the file is missing.

What is the reason for this error? I could be able to use the Web service in another Web Application. Problem comes when I use with C++ Application. 
**Is there any other good way to use Web service in C++ Application?**

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't matter header file shows is red icon, if your application compiles.
2. First you check your project folder if there is any file physically exist with name `Hello.h`. if not something wrong.

Try this ways to fix it.

- Right click on the web reference in the solution explorer and click `update web reference`
- Remove the web reference and try to add it again
- Make sure to select a project type with .NET support
- In [this site](http://www.webservicex.net/WS/wscatlist.aspx) there are some sample web services. So create a fresh `VS CLR console project` and try to add one of them as web reference. By that you can check if there is any issue with your visual studio.
- If `Hello.h` file exist in some `sub folder` of your `project folder`, then add the `sub folder` to the include path of your project.

Here One test project I added a reference to a web service and even header file shows with red icon. but it compiles properly.

[image]

Comment: Yeah your first point is correct I just realized after posting a question :) . hello.h should be automatically created as i mentioned  it is missing; that's the issue. 
I tried to add web reference using the site you mentioned. Again same problem, error comes.
fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'net_webservicexwww.h': No such file or directory c1xx

Comment: Can you double click on the file in solution explorer and open it? If not try to run visual studio with administrator permission. And also if your project is located at `C` drive try to move to other drive. then start as fresh project from begin. If anything doesn't work, try to repair `VS`.

Comment: No i couldn't open. And followed the two methods as well. No success. Thanks for the help. Will try in different installation